# Implementing multiple spring httpsecurity having same pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using Spring Security XML configuration, how can I define multiple httpsecurity having the same pattern like:-pattern="/**". So that security changes based on where it has been deployed, local or prod.

I am already using `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER` and `CAS_FILTER` but with different pattern. But now I need to bypass `CAS_FILTER` based on where it has been deployed with same pattern.

Comment: Fix grammar, highlight code